# VT-d enabled in BIOS settings and virtualbox still reading VT-x disabled error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, bios, kali-linux

so I attempted to run a virtual machine in VirtualBox and got the following error with details:
"Failed to open a session with a virtual machine ... VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes"

Now I am aware this is a duplicate question, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746462/error-vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disa), but what makes mine different is that the issue is persisting even after enabling the settings. I went into BIOS settings on my ASUS PC and enabled the VT-d settings as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42830011/8955624) on another duplicate question. When I double check under Advanced Settings->System Agent Configuration Settings the VT-d function is enabled under BIOS. However when I attempt to run the virtual machine I am still getting the same error. I am attempting to run Kali Linux on a VirtualBox machine.

If anyone could point me in the direction of a potential solution that would be of great help.

thank you very kindly

Comment: Some people have had luck disabling and re-enabling that setting. Is there a "virtualisation extensions" setting that also needs to be enabled? .

Comment: You enabled VT-d or VT-x they are two entirely separate features

Comment: yes i know but i didn't find any VT-x option anywhere in the ASUS bios settings. I went one by one through pretty much every setting and didn't see a VT-x option anywhere. maybe i missed it? if so do you know where it can be found pls?

Comment: Hi so I went into Advanced -> CPU Configurations and found Intel VT-x technology, it was greyed out/couldn't change it but it said it was "Supported" already... however VirtualBox still is not running. any advice on what to do from here?

Comment: Update in case if anyone has new input.... i tried quickly setting up a VM with ubuntu server and it worked just fine... so the underlying problem is not with virtualbox itself